# how to split one string in a column into two string pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have 2 STRING dataframe, each data is given name as dataset and colloquial.

dataframe colloquial:

```
|**wrong**  | **correct** |    
|sheis      | she is      |    
|taht       | that        |    
|diedwhen   | died when   |
```

The second dataframe is dataset with specific column that I use that look like this:

dataframe dataset['review'] :

```
review    
[shewas, wrong, but, her, intentions, are, good]     
[is, taht, you]     
[he, diedwhen, he, was, young]
```

I want to change the wrong word in the dataset['review'] into the correct word according to dataframe colloquial. I use this:

```
normalizad_word = pd.read_excel("colloquial.xlsx")    

normalizad_word_dict = {}    

for index, row in normalizad_word.iterrows():    
    if row[0] not in normalizad_word_dict:    
        normalizad_word_dict[row[0]] = row[1]     

def normalized_term(document):    
    return [normalizad_word_dict[term] if term in normalizad_word_dict else term for term in document]     

dataset['review_normalized'] = dataset['review'].apply(normalized_term)     

dataset['review_normalized']
```

BUT the result is like this:

```
review_normalized    
[she was, wrong, but, her, intentions, are, good]    
[is, that, you]    
[he, died when, he, was, young]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
review_normalized    
[she, was, wrong, but, her, intentions, are, good]    
[is, that, you]    
[he, died, when, he, was, young]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `normalized_term` function:

```
def normalized_term(document):
    result = []
    for term in document:
        if term in normalizad_word_dict:
            for word in normalizad_word_dict[term].split(' '):
                result.append(word)
        else:
            result.append(term)
    return result
```

Or if you want to use inline loop:

```
import itertools    
def normalized_term(document):
    return list(itertools.chain(*[normalizad_word_dict[term].split() if term in normalizad_word_dict else term.split() for term in document]))
```